# Why can't I login to Agora RTM

Tags: flutter, agora

**Hi guys I'm new to agora and I'm having issues logging in on agora rtm. how do I go about it?... I keep getting an error which saysLogin error: Instance of 'AgoraRtmClientException'. Any idea how I can go about solving this?.Or does this error come from the console?.... Please help guys I've been stuck on this for so long.**

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:agora_rtm/agora_rtm.dart';



import '../../../logs.dart';
import '../../../message.dart';


class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyApp2State createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> {
  final _userId = TextEditingController();
  final _channelName = TextEditingController();

  AgoraRtmClient? _client;
  AgoraRtmChannel? _channel;
  LogController logController = LogController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createClient();
  }

  void _createClient() async {
    _client = await AgoraRtmClient.createInstance(appId);
    _client!.onMessageReceived = (AgoraRtmMessage message, String peerId) {
      logController.addLog("Private Message from " + peerId + ": " + message.text);
    };
    _client!.onConnectionStateChanged = (int state, int reason) {
      logController.addLog('Connection state changed: ' + state.toString() + ', reason: ' + reason.toString());
      if (state == 5) {
        _client!.logout();
        logController.addLog('Logout.');
      }
    };
  }

  void _login(BuildContext context) async {
    String userId = _userId.text;
    if (userId.isEmpty) {
      print('Please input your user id to login.');
      return;
    }

    try {
      await _client!.login(null, userId);
      logController.addLog('Login success: ' + userId);
      _joinChannel(context);
    } catch (errorCode) {
      print('Login error: ' + errorCode.toString());
    }
  }

  void _joinChannel(BuildContext context) async {
    String channelId = _channelName.text;
    if (channelId.isEmpty) {
      logController.addLog('Please input channel id to join.');
      return;
    }

    try {
      _channel = await _createChannel(channelId);
      await _channel!.join();
      logController.addLog('Join channel success.');
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MessageScreen(
                client: _client!,
                channel: _channel!,
                logController: logController,
              )));
    } catch (errorCode) {
      print('Join channel error: ' + errorCode.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<AgoraRtmChannel> _createChannel(String name) async {
    AgoraRtmChannel? channel = await _client!.createChannel(name);
    channel!.onMemberJoined = (AgoraRtmMember member) {
      logController.addLog("Member joined: " + member.userId + ', channel: ' + member.channelId);
    };
    channel.onMemberLeft = (AgoraRtmMember member) {
      logController.addLog("Member left: " + member.userId + ', channel: ' + member.channelId);
    };
    channel.onMessageReceived = (AgoraRtmMessage message, AgoraRtmMember member) {
      logController.addLog("Public Message from " + member.userId + ": " + message.text);
    };
    return channel;
  }

  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Agora Real Time Message'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(controller: _userId, decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'User ID')),
            TextField(controller: _channelName, decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Channel')),
            OutlinedButton(child: Text('Login'), onPressed: () => _login(context)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include the full error?

Comment: Login error: Instance of 'AgoraRtmClientException'